# Keycloak admin rest api user sessions

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm using keycloak admin rest api to fetch all the active user sessions with the below api.

https://example.com/auth/admin/realms/AMB/clients/a1b2c3e4d5/user-sessions

I'm using LDAP active directory. When I call the above endpoint, I'm facing the below error. Could you please help me out?

ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-217) Uncaught server error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: LDAP Query failed
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind@2.12.1.redhat-00001//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider._wrapAsIOE(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:509)